# extract pixels from an image, as new small images

Tags: image, jpeg, extract, pixel

Can anyone suggest a method I can use to extract pixels from an image. Not as text, in print, but as an image itself. I want to get all the seperate pixels from an image as new images. One pixel per image. The only solutions I can find are ones where the pixels are printed, maybe I'm not using the right keywords when searching, but hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

The pictures in question are jpg, and there are about 900 of them which I would all like to turn into seperate pixel images.

Thanks!

Arantxa

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would want to do this, but if you use ImageMagick, which is installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX (preferably via `homebrew`) and Windows, you can do this:

```
convert in.jpg -crop 1x1 p%d.jpg
```

and you will get `p0.jpg`, `p1.jpg` and so on.

We can test that like this...

```
# Create a 4x1 black-white gradient
convert -size 4x1 gradient:black-white in.jpg

# Chop it into 1x1 pixel image lumps
convert in.jpg -crop 1x1 p%d.jpg

# Check what we got - yes, 4 images each 1x1
identify p*
p0.jpg JPEG 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 160B 0.000u 0:00.000
p1.jpg[1] JPEG 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 160B 0.000u 0:00.000
p2.jpg[2] JPEG 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 160B 0.000u 0:00.000
p3.jpg[3] JPEG 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 160B 0.000u 0:00.000

# Scale the little lumps up and append them side-by-side to see result - add border so white square is visible
convert p*.jpg -scale 100 +append -bordercolor red -border 5x5 out.png
```

[image]